# Copy specific graph from dbpedia to Virtuoso graphs

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso, dotnetrdf, triples

I am trying to copy a specific graph from *dbpedia.org* to *local virtuoso* using **dotnetrdf** in C#. E.g. `dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cyclists_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics`

Code below gets graph from Virtuoso and asserts all its triples to my new graph. Then I am adding new graph to Virtuoso, But it doesn't work.

**Example code**

```
 IGraph g = new Graph()
 IGraph nG = new Graph()
 nG.BaseUri = new Uri(linkToDbpedia);

 UriLoader.Load(g, new Uri(linkToDbpedia))


 foreach(Triple t in g.Triples) {

   nG.Assert(t);

 }

 VirtuosoManager manager = new VirtuosoManager("localhost", 1111, VirtuosoManager.DefaultDB, "dba", "dba");
 PersistentTripleStore store = new PersistentTripleStore(manager);

 store.Add(nG);
 store.Flush();
```

My main task is to send SPARQL queries to my own Virtuoso db, because it takes less time.

Answer (score 0):

In the second I tried to copy graph using *sparql queries*, but it was useless because In some cases my **t.Object** its *Uri* in other cases its *Integer*, *Double*, and *Date*.

This way Is not fully studied, so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is correct answer :3**

```
VirtuosoManager manager = new VirtuosoManager("localhost", 1111, VirtuosoManager.DefaultDB, "dba", "dba");

IGraph g = new Graph();
UriLoader.Load(g, new Uri(linkToDBpedia));

g.BaseUri = new Uri(linkToDBpedia);

manager.saveGraph(g);
```